# Unity Android: Change ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik From Code

Tags: android, plugins, unity-game-engine

Is it possible from C# or Android Java, to change the value of unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik?

Normally you set this in the Manifest.xml file but I like to just turn it on while my Java UI is on screen.

Comment: Why cant you just change it in the manifest? Its located in Plugins -> Android -> Manifest

Comment: I only want it changed for a short time.  Normally the app does not need it changed.